# How to log in to a system what was created without any users. (Selected, in installer, to create user, but it didn't happen) (Fedora if that matters)

Tags: linux, fedora, system-installation

I just installed Fedora (37, KDE spin), and after booting into it I get presented with a log-in screen I *can't get through using the user credentials I set up in the installer*!

So how do I get in??

Note though this situation was created by the Fedora installer, I'm also tagging this question with "Linux" and not only "Fedora" since it looks like something that could happen in other distros as well.

Note I did choose to enable a root account during the installation, but I want to know if there is any way to **get in *without using the root account*, because:

1. I've read that it's best to never log on as root, and I want to stick to that.
2. Since the standard/admin user I chose to create in the installer failed to get created/enabled, there's a chance the root user didn't get created either (but I don't want to test that because of 1., above)
3. Since I did everything the installer asked and it put me in this situation without me doing anything fancy, I am just hoping there's a way to get out of the situation without doing anything fancy.  (Is there a default user that gets created if no users are specified during installation, with some username and password I can input.)

More notes:

- I think the installation maybe have been cut short for some reason, because the screen went black after the **progress bar was only maybe *a fifth* of the way full**.
- That black screen state happened without me seeing any message telling me to **forcibly shut down the computer**, but after a while staring a the black screen and seeing no flash drive activity (thank goodness this one has a light), I had to do just that.  I would think if the installation process requires a reboot, that would happen automatically.
- The last message I noticed on the progress bar (at around 20% full) was **"Installing software 100%"** (it had reached 100% and held there for maybe a minute, then went to black screen)
- After (forcible) reboot (and grub selection), the computer went straight into a screen that looked like the installer GUI, but with no desktop.  It was called **"Initial Setup"**.    It did come with a big description box available, in which the thing that stood out for me was "The Initial Setup  screen is shown [...] assuming the following conditions have been met [...] graphical environment you have installed is not GNOME [and other conditinos]"
- On the post-boot "Initial Setup" screen, in the top right corner, I noticed an indicator that the **keyboard was in "us" mode**, even though in the installer I had chosen Dvorak (this doesn't seem like a huge deal, though, since the installer did tell me it couldn't accommodate any keyboard other than the default (US, QWERTY) and the keyboard I was choosing would apply for the installed system only, not during installation)
- On the post-boot "Initial Setup" screen, in the middle of the screen (in the same place as there had been the six boxes with installer options in the main installer ("Keyboard", "Time & Date", "Installation Destination", "Network & Host Name", "Root Account", "User Creation"), there was just one of the boxes, "User Creation", but instead of reading "user [my chosen username] will be created" in the box, it read **"No user account will be created"**.   I realize I could have gone through the process of choosing another user then, but I trusted that the user account I had chosen in the main installer step had already been created.

By the way, this seems worthy of one or more bug reports of some kind, at least for the user account I set up not having been created, but I'm not sure how to do that.  I'd be happy to do that if I knew where and how!

UPDATE 1:  I eventually tried logging in as the root user, but that did not work (so the installer failed to create either account).

UPDATE 2:  I did a fresh re-install (actually the system *froze* (vice black-screening) at just "Installing software 35%"...but the rest of the outcome was the same:  had to forcibly power down, and upon reboot was put into that "Initial Setup" screen again.  This time around I did *not* trust that the users were created, so I took it up on the offer to create a (2nd) normal/admin user.  I am now writing this from within Fedora, but the installer is absolutely not working properly.  I don't know if I trust the installation, and I may try again.  In the meantime, **I am still open to an answer to my basic question of how to get in to the system (and maybe create a new admin user or enable the root user) when going through the GUI log-in screen is not an option...and I'm also open to the answer being "it's impossible."**.

Comment: It looks like you made an OEM install somehow - since OEM installations can't assume anything about the user, they have that type of post-install setup screens with a step for creating a user.

Comment: Is that the only difference?  I did specify to create a user, but if it didn't do it for some reason, that's the same as an OEM installation?  Anyway, that's good to know.  So, then, if someone orders a laptop with Fedora pre-installed, how is that person supposed to get past the sign-in screen?

Comment: Whilst you should be cautious with the root account it’s situations like this where you can use it.  Login as root, create your user with a password, make sure that user has sudo permissions, log out and login as your new user.

Comment: An OEM install wouldn't even have a password for root set, so the post install setup would have a prompt to create one. I guess by setting a root password but somehow creating an OEM install, you got a weird edge case.

Comment: OEM Linux installations are often full of junk and weird settings. If I were you I'd simply reinstall from scratch.

Comment: I just tried logging in as root.  No dice.  Looks like the installer failed on both accounts (no pun intended!).

Comment: So yes it kind of looks like an OEM-type installation, but if the account steps were missed who knows what else was missed.  Right now I'm trying to re-install.

Comment: @muru Not that is an actual OEM installation, but for curiosity's sake would they really work the same way?  Meaning, as happened to me, the user gets one and only one shot at the "Initial Setup" screen, and if that opportunity to create a user is missed then the user can never get into the system??